# ExtJS textfield with LabelAlign Top Left

Tags: html, css, extjs

I am using EXTJS and I'm trying to line up my field labels at the top left, which from my understanding is supposed to be the default setting for `labelAlign: 'top'`. However, my labels (except for the checkbox one) are lining up at the top right. Does anyone know how to fix it so all the field labels line up at the top left?

The code is below:

```
Ext.define('ELA.view.interpreter.InterpreterForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.interpreterForm',

    require: [
        'Ext.form.field.ComboBox'
    ],

    id: 'interpreterForm',
    title: 'Interpreter Form',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    modal: true,
    init: function () {
        //console.log('client list loaded');
    },
    initComponent: function () {

        this.items = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'anchor',
                height: 700,
                width: 750,
                padding: '2px',
                frame: true,
                cls: 'elaform',
                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelAlign: 'top'

                },

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'tabpanel',
                        activeTab: 0,
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        plain: true,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        defaults: {
                            autoScroll: true,
                            bodyPadding: 10
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                layout: 'anchor',
                                height: 700,
                                width: 750,
                                padding: '2px',
                                frame: true,
                                cls: 'elaform',
                                title: 'Details',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                        items: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'hidden',
                                                id: 'txtInterpreterFormIntId',
                                                name: 'IntId'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Last',
                                                        id: 'txtEditLastName',
                                                        name: 'LastName',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px'



                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'First',
                                                        id: 'txtEditFirstName',
                                                        name: 'FirstName',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',

                                                    },
                                                    {

                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'DBA',
                                                        id: 'txtEditDBA',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',

                                                        name: 'DBA'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },

                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Ph#1',
                                                        id: 'txtEditPhone1',
                                                        name: 'Phone1',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        labelWidth: 30
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Ph#2',
                                                        id: 'txtEditPhone2',
                                                        name: 'Phone2',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        labelWidth: 30
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Fax',
                                                        id: 'txtEditFax',
                                                        name: 'Fax',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        labelWidth: 30
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },

                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Email',
                                                        id: 'txtEditEmail',
                                                        name: 'IntEMail',
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        labelWidth: 31,
                                                        fieldWidth: 125

                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Beeper',
                                                        id: 'txtEditBeeper',
                                                        name: 'Beeper',
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: .5,
                                                        labelWidth: 65
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },

                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                        items: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Street',
                                                        id: 'txtEditStreet',
                                                        name: 'Street',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        labelWidth: 30
                                                    },


                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'City',
                                                        id: 'txtEditCity',
                                                        name: 'City',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        labelWidth: 30

                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'displayfield',
                                                        flex: .5
                                                    }

                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'State',
                                                        id: 'txtEditState',
                                                        name: 'State',
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: .5,
                                                        labelWidth: 30
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Zip',
                                                        id: 'txtEditZip',
                                                        labelWidth: 30,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: .5,
                                                        name: 'Zip'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Country',
                                                        id: 'txtEditCountry',
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: .75,
                                                        labelWidth: 45,
                                                        name: 'Country'
                                                    }


                                                ]
                                            },

                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [


                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Status',
                                                        id: 'txtEditStatus',
                                                        labelWidth: 32,

                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        name: 'Stat',
                                                        flex: 1
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'datefield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'OrigDate',
                                                        name: 'OrigDate',
                                                        id: 'txtEditOrigDate',
                                                        labelWidth: 49,
                                                        fieldWidth: 120,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        format: 'm/d/Y',
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'datefield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Updated',
                                                        id: 'txtEditUpdated',
                                                        labelWidth: 30,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        readOnly: true,
                                                        name: 'Updated',

                                                        format: 'm/d/y H:i:s A'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },

                                             {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [

                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'State1099',
                                                        id: 'txtEditState1099',
                                                        labelWidth: 30,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: .5,
                                                        name: 'State1099'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'State1099Amt',
                                                        id: 'txtEditState1099Amt',
                                                        labelWidth: 30,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        flex: .5,
                                                        name: 'State1099Amt'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Corporation',
                                                        id: 'chkEditCorporation',
                                                        name: 'Corporation',
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        bodyStyle: 'padding: 2px 10px;'
                                                        //flex: .5
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'IRS# / SSN#',
                                                        id: 'txtEditSocSecNum',
                                                        //labelWidth: 90,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        name: 'SocSecNum',
                                                        //flex: .5
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },

                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                        items: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {

                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Note',
                                                        id: 'txtEditNote',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        name: 'Note'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {

                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Referred By',
                                                        id: 'txtEditReferredBy',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        name: 'ReferredBy'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'container',
                                                layout: 'hbox',
                                                items: [
                                                    {

                                                        xtype: 'textfield',
                                                        fieldLabel: 'Unavailable',
                                                        id: 'txtEditUnavailable',
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        padding: '2px',
                                                        name: 'Unavailable'
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                layout: 'anchor',
                                height: 450,
                                width: 690,
                                padding: '2px',
                                frame: true,
                                cls: 'elaform',
                                title: 'Languages',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                        store: 'InterpreterLanguagesStore',
                                        columns: [
                                            { text: 'IntId', dataIndex: 'IntId', hidden: true },
                                            { text: 'Language', dataIndex: 'Language' }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Have you enabled RTL?

Comment: Like mentioned above, it's probable that you have rtl enabled. Here is a fiddle created with your exact setup: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sm8

Answer (score 0):

if you use architect. do not worry, this is easily solved! Just click on the magnet on the left in the align configuration settings in the label component. In the text before the word left, put a space. Then remove the magnet and save.

If you don’t use architect, just put a space before the left word in this way `labelAlign: ' left'`